# Multiple monitors with xfreerdp and Xvfb

Tags: xvfb, xfreerdp

I am trying to start an X server with multiple screens on a single Xvfb like this:

```
Xvfb :50 -screen 0 1792x1120x24 -screen 1 1792x1120x24
```

and start an RDP connection which will use those two screens:

```
DISPLAY=:50; xfreerdp /w:1792 /h:1120 /monitors:0,1 /multimon /u:... /p... /v:...
```

This doesn't work like this, the xfreerdp process crashes. I've tried some combinations of `/span` and monitor numbers and `/multimon:force` and nothing worked. When I'm trying the same with one monitor and one Xvfb screen it works. I also don't understand how do I set resolutions per screen/monitor in xfreerdp since I have just one of each /w and /h.

Also tried to `xfreerdp /monitor-list` after starting Xvfb with one or two screens. After starting Xvfb with one screen, the monitor-list printed it correctly. But with two xvfb screens, the monitor-list printed nothing.

Thanks for any answers or even hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get multiple virtual monitors for `xfreerdp` by using `Xvnc` server (part of `tigervnc-server`) and `xrandr` instead of `Xvfb`:

```
Xvnc :50 -screen 0 1600x600x24 &
DISPLAY=:50
xrandr --setmonitor screen0 800/400x600/300+0+0 VNC-0
xrandr --setmonitor screen1 800/400x600/300+800+0 none
xfreerdp /multimon:force /monitors:0,1 /u:... /p... /v:...
```

Answer (score 2):

> start an RDP connection which will use those two screens ... `DISPLAY=:50`

X screens are not monitors. You usually have a single X screen with multiple monitors (by displaying different parts of the single framebuffer on different monitors). Monitors are comparatively new (they came with the `xrandr` extension), while screens are pretty old, and rarely used today. Screens always have different framebuffers, but can share a single X server connection. But basically no X application is written in a way to actually use different screens.

Your first Xvfb screen is at `:50.0`, your second screen is at `:50.1`, and `:50` is short for `:50.0`, so starting `xfreerdp` in the way described will only use the first screen.

So you'd need `xfreerdp` to use multiple screens on the client machine, and I do not know if `xfreerdp` can even do that. At least I don't see any options that I'd use to configure that.

What `/multimon` does is to look at the monitors that are associated to a single display/screen (i.e., what you get with `xrandr`). But `Xvfb -screen` does not set it up this way.

Comment: makes sense, thank you! but is there a way I can connect with xfreerdp and get multiple monitors on a single xvfb screen/display (in some geometry...)?